# Slim - change settings in middleware

Tags: slim

Am I able to change settings in middleware?
What I want to accomplish is to change error handling engine depending on route.
For some routes I want error to be displayed in HTML and for some (ajax) as JSON.
I think that middleware is the right place but how to change settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to change error handler by overwriting the error handler key in your container:

```php
$app->add(function($req, $res, $next){
    //$this is an instance of Slim\Container
    $this['errorHandler'] = new SomeErrorHandler();

    return $next($req, $res);
});
```

Comment: You do not need $this->getContainer() as your comment says, $this is actually the Container not Slim\App... you simply need to use $this->get('')